# How does addresses of -5 to 256 numbers work in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, memory, equality, memory-address

I'm just trying to get the addresses of variables in python and came across something odd.

I have assigned some numbers to a variable and checking the Equality and Identity of those variables.

```
>>>a=-10
>>>a is -10
```

**Output:**

> False

---

```
>>>a=-5
>>>a is -5
```

**Output:**

> True

---

```
>>>a=256
>>>a is 256
```

**Output:**

> True

---

```
>>>a=257
>>>a is 257
```

**Output:**

> False

I'm just curious what's happening behind the scenes in range `-5` to `256`.

Can someone please explain.

It's something like the one mentioned here - https://ubuntuforums.org/archive/index.php/t-1848655.html

I'm using:

```
Python: 3.7.5
Ubuntu: 18.04
```

Comment: I believe the last output with 257 should be `False`

Comment: yup. forgot to update while pasting. Thanks for noticing.

Comment: Note, you aren't getting the address of a variable, you are getting the address of an object